# cos/sin/tan function gives different result than my calculator

Tags: r

If I enter

```
cos(90)
```

I get

```
-0.4480736
```

But my calculator gives

```
0
```

I don't get it.

```
?cos
 These functions give the obvious trigonometric functions.  They
 respectively compute the cosine, sine, tangent, arc-cosine,
 arc-sine, arc-tangent, and the two-argument arc-tangent.
```

Obvious?

Comment: Read into the difference between degrees and radians...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help(Trig)`:

> Angles are in radians, not degrees, for the standard versions (i.e., a right angle is *π/2*), and in ‘half-rotations’ for `cospi` etc.

```
> cos(pi)
[1] -1
> cos(2*pi)
[1] 1
```

Mind that:

```
> pi
[1] 3.141593
```